# Drawing an outline with THREE.EdgesGeometry (Error: THREE.EdgesGeometry is not a constructor)

Tags: three.js

I am trying to draw an outline to a 2D polyline mesh with three js. Doing some research I've seen that THREE.EdgesGeometry paints the edges of a given geometry. When I tried to use it with my polylineMesh the next error occured:

Uncaught TypeError: THREE.EdgesGeometry is not a constructor.

The next code is the one I'm using:

```
var zShape = new THREE.Shape(finalShape);                               
var polylineGeometry = new THREE.ShapeGeometry(zShape);
var polylineMesh = new THREE.Mesh(polylineGeometry, new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
        color: 0x00ff00,
        side: THREE.DoubleSide,
        transparent: true,
        opacity: 0.25
}));
var geo = new THREE.EdgesGeometry( polylineGeometry  ); // or WireframeGeometry
var mat = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color: 0xffffff } );
var wireframe = new THREE.LineSegments( geo, mat );
polylineMesh.add( wireframe );
```

Here is an image of the polylineMesh that I'm trying to create an outline.

[Polyline Mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfaFI.png)

I updated the three.js release to 138 but the error keeps showing.
Is there something wrong with my code or can someone help me figuring out how to solve this error?

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Please show what you do with a live example. It seems to work fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/1sz4npgh/

Comment: Hi I'm not sure I can do a live example. I'm using an API called Forge Viewer and this API uses Three.js version 71. I've been researching and it's incompatible with the newest versions of Three.js. Thank you anyway!